# Can I detect whether CSS filter effects are supported?

Tags: javascript, css

[CSS Filter Effects](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#FilterProperty) is currently in draft, but already supported by chrome. It provides the possibility to apply effects to images:

> The CSS filter property provides for effects like blurring or color shifting on an element’s rendering before the element is displayed. Filters are commonly used to adjust the rendering of an image, a background, or a border.
>
> Included in the CSS standard are several functions that achieve predefined effects. You can also reference a filter specified in SVG with a URL to an SVG filter element. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility))

As far as I know, CSS filters effects are only supported in Chrome 18+ yet, however is it possible to detect the availability of CSS filter effects via JavaScript or some CSS tricks?

Comment: **This question does not show any research effort;** it is unclear or not useful http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Zeta best salvage-edit i've ever seen on here :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)** Javascript library for CSS3 feature detection I believe.

According to the following links, (as of Modernizr 2.6) Modernizr can now be used for CSS filter detection:

http://www.browserleaks.com/modernizr#filter

http://modernizr.com/news/ (under the test improvements section).

and http://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-260/.

Comment: @user125697: The modernizr team should really keep their documentation up to date. Sorry for the inconvenience.