# How can I detect whether a browser supports a css property using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I want to detect whether the browser supports a CSS property using javascript (particularly, whether "filter" is supported)? How can I do so?

I tried the following function

```
 supportsCssStyle: function (prop) {
        var div = document.createElement('div'),
            vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),
            len = vendors.length;

        if (prop in div.style) return true;

        prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function (val) {
            return val.toUpperCase();
        });

        while (len--) {
            if (vendors[len] + prop in div.style) {
                // browser supports box-shadow. Do what you need.
                // Or use a bang (!) to test if the browser doesn't.
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },
```

but it is not working

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189905/can-i-detect-whether-css-filter-effects-are-supported

Comment: I don;t want to use Modernizr

Comment: What does not work? Your code works for me.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Oriol in the comments, my original answer was wrong (yet somehow ended up with 3 upvotes).  Here's a more reliable way.

```js
function supportsProperty(prop) {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.cssText = prop + ":initial";
  return el.style[prop] === "initial";
}

function supportsValue(prop, value) {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.cssText = prop + ":" + value;
  return el.style[prop] === value;
}

console.log("filter", supportsProperty("filter")); // true for me
console.log("-ms-flex", supportsProperty("-ms-flex")); // false for me
console.log("position:sticky", supportsValue("position", "sticky")); // true for me
```

Comment: How is using `in` on a computed style different than using it on `document.createElement('div').style`?

Comment: @Oriol Using `.style` will only give you the properties explicitly set on the element.  I suppose you could try setting the property on a new element and checking if it stayed applied, but I'm not sure how all browsers deal with that.  Some might keep the invalid property, while others (Firefox, at least) will throw it out.

Comment: But even properties which are not set are defined as getters/setters. OP's `"filter" in document.createElement('div').style` works just like your `"filter" in window.getComputedStyle(document.createElement("div"))`

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is aimed at a JS solution, but since it's a CSS problem that's being solved,it might be of interest that the `@supports` feature query is fairly well supported now...except...(surprise!) Internet Explorer (Edge supports it, though - full list here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-featurequeries)